# Can't activate Visual Studio with product key

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, license-key

To be short: 
What do to if you have a Visual Studio product key, but can't find how to activate it?

In my case this was VS 2017 Professional.

I was triying to find how to activate VS. After few unsuccesfull attempts I've Googled for it and [found](http://sanderstechnology.com/2017/visual-studio-2017-using-a-product-key/15163) that there must be a "**Unlock with a Product Key**" button.

[image: Activation window]

But in my case there wasn't such button. I had absolutely the same window just without "Unlock with a Product Key" option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I spent some more time with Google, I found an [official MS article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442061.aspx). 
And there was an interesting detail:

> Start Visual Studio in **Run as Administrator** mode.

I tried and it worked. The "Unlock with a Product Key" option appeared instantly.

*Sorry if I'm doing something wrong. I wasn't sure if it's okay to answer my own question, but I really dissappointed when I hadn't found any similar questions on SO.*

Comment: Does still not work for me. I keep on getting an error saying "A failure occurred while applying the product key". This is a fresh install of Win10 and VS 2019

Comment: Hitting the same one as @Damian here, it's pretty frustrating especially as it was already hard enough getting individual license keys instead of the subscriptions they're trying to push down everyone's throats. I can't tell if it's my key that doesn't work or if there's an error somewhere else.

Comment: Mystery solved, and that's funny. So I got that license from my IT admin who bought a bunch of them for our team on our request. I  ended up on a support live chat for VS subscribers where the guy offered to verify my license key, and here's what he said:
Thank you for the information, I was able to validate that this is a valid key however this is for Visio Professional 2019 and not actually Visual Studio Professional.

oops! :D

Comment: My issue was also the license key. I got a new license key from my support team which they obtained from Microsoft support. Apparently the 2017 pro key should work with 2019 also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem on Windows 10 AFTER Updating to Creators Fall Update.
But Administator Rights had not solved this problem.
But in the Visual Studio Installation Tool i could make an update. After this (long time go) update i could start visual studio pro 2017 and it detected my old test licence and i had the button for the key.
It seems that during update something happened with the registry? An updated solved this.